# Как составить SQL запрос на удаление, с условием, что существует запись по другому условию?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть таблица article_tags

```
id  art_id  tag_id
1     81     21
2     81     22
3     82     23
4     83     24
```

Также есть две переменные:
`$old_tag = 21` - тег, который нужно убрать,
`$new_tag = 22` - тег, который нужно оставить

Как сделать запрос, чтобы убрать запись c `tag_id = $old_tag`, в случае если существует запись с таким же `art_id`, но с `tag_id = $new_tag`? 
в данном случае убрать должно первую запись.

Comment: Я правильно понял идею что надо убрать дубли art_id с более меньшим tag_id?

Comment: @plesser Только надо убрать не все дубли, а тот, в котором `tag_id = $old_tag`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delete from article_tags t1
where tag_id = $old_tag
and exists(select 1 from article_tags t2 where t1.art_id=t2.art_id
  and tag_id = $new_tag)
```